# Applets in Java

Tags: java

An applet is a special kind of Java program that is designed to be transmitted over the

Internet and automatically executed by a Java-compatible web browser.

**Is the Homepage of Google,Yahoo Facebook etc. an Applet ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Applets are downloaded stand-alone programs. Google and so on use server-side interpreted code that sends an http response to the client browsers, which is a significantly different setup.

Comment: @ Nathaniel Ford Then what we can call Google homepage? Plz give me one example of Applet.

Comment: A simple google search for "Sample Java Applet" lends links such as this: http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/Java/applets.htm However, you should note that java applets are not in wide use anymore.